# .Xap file incompatible with XNA Content Pipeline version

Tags: c#, xna, pipeline, xap, xact

I was looking through files that were installed with XNA framework and after that I got back to programming and I got an error:

```
The .xap file was created with a version of XACT that is incompatible with
the XNA Framework Content Pipeline version used by this project. Refer to the 
documentation for options to resolve this mismatch.
```

I don't know what it means. How can I fix it?

Comment: I did try to find what is the issue but I can't find out what is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating from a differect XNA version, such as XNA 3.1 to 4.0, you need to convert your XACT files to the latest version.

There is an in depth guide [here](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/09/23/10067171.aspx?Redirected=true), but I'll highlight the points.

1. Make a backup copy of your `.xap` file if you would like to keep a copy of the `.xap` file from before the upgrade.
2. On a system with XNA Game Studio 4.0 installed, click on the Start menu > All Programs, > Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0 > Tools |> Microsoft Cross-Platform Audio Creation Tool 3 (XACT3). This is the latest version and will allow you to update your file.
3. In the XACT3 tool, open the `.xap` file from the project that you upgraded to XNA 4.  When it loads, you should see the following message in the XACT UI:

   ```
   This project file was created with the March 2009 release of XACT.
   You are running the February 2010 release.
   If you save this project, it will be saved as the current version
   and may no longer work with the version of  XACT it was originally
   created with.
   ```
4. Click <kbd>Ok</kbd> to upgrade the `.xap` project to the new February 2010 format.
5. Save the `.xap` project in the XACT UI and close the XACT UI.
6. Go back to Visual Studio 2010, open the project that you upgraded from XNA Game Studio 3.1 to 4.0 and choose to build it again.

Their is also [this thread](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/33066/189467.aspx) over on MSDN saying you can simply convert the `.xap` by opening it in XACT3, Saving, and rebuilding the project

Comment: So this happens when you update your xna project. Well the project was made in 4.0 so i don't know why this happened. And I can't find xap file in my project directory. Please help!!!

Comment: I was looking on the web and I found out that .xap file is audio file playable on xna right? The thing is that i don't have any audio that I play... Is this a bug? I will make a new project and copy-paste code in new project and i'll get beck to you and tell you if it works...

Comment: Wait... So you mean your not even trying to play a .xap file? And you also don't have one in your project? Have you tried creating a new project and see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug! I just copied my code in different project and it was ok! Thanks anyway.